# Java EE 1.5 Servlet – http method OPTIONS gives “405 Method Not Allowed”

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, servlets, cors

I am using “Java EE 1.5, with support for JAX-WS Annotations to create a web service.

My web service can be called without a problem from Soap UI.
I am trying to call it from chrome using javascript and JQuery. I am hitting a cross sight security problem. I am awear of the headers that need to be added to the call and I have added them and verified they are present in Soap UI.
Looking at the chrome log I can see that it is sending a http call with the method “OPTIONS” to the webservice and it is getting a response “405 (Method Not Allowed)”

From what I can work out something is intercepting the method “OPTIONS” before it gets to my servlet. “POST” requests get through without any issue.
Does anyone know how to configure a Java EE 1.5 servlett to receive the OPTIONS HTTP method? I have googled this but with no luck.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>connectionInfo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.wsdlgen.Main_ptImpl</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>connectionInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/connectionInfo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Java Code:

```
package ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.wsdlgen;

import ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.WeblogicSensor;
import ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.wsdlgentypes.ObjectFactory;
import ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.wsdlgentypes.RequestSOAEndpointsMessageType;
import ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.wsdlgentypes.ResponseSOAEndpointsMessageType;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService(name = "main_pt", targetNamespace = "urn:WLAdminServerSensor", serviceName = "connectionInfoService", portName = "connectionInfo", wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/wsdl/connectionInfoService.wsdl")
@XmlSeeAlso( { ObjectFactory.class })
@javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding(style = javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle = javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class Main_ptImpl {
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext ctxt;

    public Main_ptImpl() {
    }

    @javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @Action(input = "urn:WLAdminServerSensor/querySOAEndpoints", output = "urn:WLAdminServerSensor/main_pt/querySOAEndpointsResponse")
    @WebMethod(action = "urn:WLAdminServerSensor/querySOAEndpoints")
    @WebResult(name = "responseSOAEndpointsMessage", targetNamespace = "http://ic.ac.uk.icdev.rjmtest.wladminserversensor.types", partName = "requestSOAEndpointsOutputPart")
    public ResponseSOAEndpointsMessageType querySOAEndpoints(@WebParam(name = "requestSOAEndpointsMessage", partName = "requestSOAEndpointsInputPart", targetNamespace = "http://ic.ac.uk.icdev.rjmtest.wladminserversensor.types")
        RequestSOAEndpointsMessageType requestSOAEndpointsInputPart) {

        MessageContext mc = ctxt.getMessageContext();

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE);        
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, PUT");
            return null;
        };

        return WeblogicSensor.execute(requestSOAEndpointsInputPart);
    }
}
```

Javascript (using JQuery) run in Chrome to call the servlet:

```
soapRequest = "<soap:Envelopexmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"xmlns:ic=\"http://ic.ac.uk.icdev.rjmtest.wladminserversensor.types\"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><ic:requestSOAEndpointsMessage><ic:Input>CallviaJQuery</ic:Input><ic:Credentials><ic:Username>weblogic</ic:Username><ic:Password>*****</ic:Password></ic:Credentials></ic:requestSOAEndpointsMessage></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: param.endpoint,
        data: {soapRequest},
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="urn:WLAdminServerSensor/querySOAEndpoints"'
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("TODO");
}).fail(function(data) {
    alert("TODO - FAIL");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this so I am posting it for the benefit of others.

I had to create my own CORS filter. I did this by creating a class that implements “javax.servlet.Filter”. I built thie by reverse engineering org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter tomcat-catalina-8.0.0-rc1.jar.zip. I had to create my own version rather than just include the apache one because I was running my javascript from a local file on my machine rather than from another website. This made the site origin get reported as null. Even if the filter was configured with allowed origins as *, the origin given from a local file (null I think) was refused.

After adjusting the code in my own version (Altering the checkRequestType function) I got it working.

I then had a web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>connectionInfo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.wsdlgen.Main_ptImpl</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>connectionInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/connectionInfo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class> ic.ac.uk.icsoa.wladminserversensor.RJMCorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

And simplified my servlet:

```
public ResponseSOAEndpointsMessageType querySOAEndpoints(@WebParam(name = "requestSOAEndpointsMessage", partName = "requestSOAEndpointsInputPart", targetNamespace = "http://ic.ac.uk.icdev.rjmtest.wladminserversensor.types")
    RequestSOAEndpointsMessageType requestSOAEndpointsInputPart) {
    return WeblogicSensor.execute(requestSOAEndpointsInputPart);
}
```

And it all worked.